# Sampling until a condition is met on a list

Tags: r

I'm looking to take the following vector:

```
v1 = c(2, 5, 7, 9, 1)
```

I want to run a loop of iterative sampling, placing the values sampled into 
a new vector `v2` and then break this process when the sum of these values are greater than 12.

This is what I have so far:

```
v2 = c()
while (sum(v2) > 12) {
  sample(v1, 1, replace = FALSE)
  if(sum(v2) > 12))
  break
}
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track. Appreciate the help.

Comment: `ss <- sample(v1); ss[cumsum(ss) < 12]` or something like that maybe?

Comment: Do you want to sample with or without replacement? Also, is your vector really large (thousands of values)? if it is the case, an iterative approach might work, but if not, the approach proposed by "thelatemail" will work. However, if you want to do a sample with replacement (as your code does) you might have to change it a bit: `ss <- sample(v1, ceiling(12/min(v1), replace=T)` to be sure that you always get enough samples to reach the minimum.

Comment: Good question, it's a small vector only. So i'm looking for no replacement hence "replace = F". I'd like to sample one number at a time until the values  surpass 12 in which case the formula stops, and I have access to the cumulative sampling that took place in another vector. My understanding was that the use of "False" would initiate no replacement thus leaving the pool to sample from at each step progressively smaller.

Answer (score 4):

I think your syntax has a problem and the use of break makes more sense with a repeat loop:

```
v1 = c(2, 5, 7, 9, 1)
v2 <- c()
repeat {
    v2 <- c(v2, sample(v1[!v1 %in% v2], 1) )
    if( sum(v2) > 12 )
    break
    }
print(v2)

[1] 5 7 9
```